# Is there a way (without dragging) to move layer into specific group in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way (without dragging) to move a layer into specific group in Photoshop? Because I have large PSD file (greater than 100 layers), moving a layer into a group by just dragging is too hard to find the specific group. Maybe some plugin can let me just right click on the layer, and select "send to..." to specific group?

I know some people would suggest that we can close groups first and then drag, but I still want to know if there is a more effective way?

Thanks.